# Using keyboard on multiple fotorama slideshows

Tags: javascript, fotorama

I've an HTML page with two Fotorama slideshows, one in the top and another in the bottom of the page.

I can't use the keyboard to move between photos for the second slideshow, even if I click with the mouse on the second slideshow trying to get the focus.
I tried also with the API with no results.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- Link to jQuery  -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     

<!-- fotorama.css & fotorama.js. -->
<link  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- 3 KB -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script>     

<!--  First slideshow -->
<div id="fotorama1" class="fotorama" data-keyboard="true" data-arrows="true">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/3.jpg">
</div>

<!--  Second slideshow -->
<div id="fotorama2" class="fotorama" data-keyboard="true" data-arrows="true">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/4.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/5.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?
Thanks in advance,
Luca